# Run script after cups print a page

Tags: linux, bash, cups

I want to execute a bash script after any page is printed in my printer, for checking a service. But I don't know if this is possible.
I've searched for a bit before asking but I haven't found anything useful.
Has someone found something about this or has experience doing something like this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could perhaps just use the print history (lpstat -W completed) and put a crontab job on every X minutes to check for recently finished jobs. Depends on the urgency and how quickly you need to trigger your script.

Comment: @urbanespaceman's suggestion is sound; you could also use `inotifywait` on the spool directory (`/var/spool/cups` in my case) and trigger the job each time a file there gets deleted, i.e. the queueing is done (it's been printed).

Comment: You could maybe cobble something together with CUPS notifications... http://blog.whatgeek.com.pt/2014/07/linux-cups-notifications/